# Modify MVC View Text Based on Querystring Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I have (2) MVC views that are going to be 99% identical aside from some textual descriptions on the page. A `bool` value provided in the call to the `View` from the querystring toggles the `Where` clause on the `IList<TModel>` that is ultimately loaded on the page from the `Index` method on the controller.

I know it's bad practice to read the querystring from the `View`, and arbitrarily selecting a single `TModel` instance to read that `bool` value also seems not correct, so I want to know how to do this.

Say I have the following text:

View1:
`<h5>Please update the Positive values</h5>`
View2:
`<h5>Please update the Negative values</h5>`

What I really want is 1 view where the `Positive` or `Negative` text values just toggle based on the following from the querystring:

`?IsPositive=true`

This value once calling the `Index` method is also available on the model, but since the model is a `IList`, I have to look at a single instance.

By the way the descriptor needs to change on about 3-4 places in the `View` so if centralizing rather than in-lining is better, I'm good with that.

What is the correct way to toggle this text based on that querystring value, that does ultimately end up on each instance in the `IList<TModel>`?

Comment: Why not just figure out the text in the controller and it it ViewBag and pass it to the view?

Comment: @{
                                var isPostive = Convert.ToBoolean(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["IsPositive"]);
                            }

Comment: Try to use that flag in the view model, as a property. ViewBag is a bad habit due to testing drawback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about this to use a view model containing your `IList<TModel>` and `IsPositive` flag, like so:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IList<TModel> MyList { get; set; }

    public bool IsPositive { get; set; }
}
```

Your action method builds the model and passes it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index(bool IsPositive)
{
    IList<TModel> myList = BuildYourList();

    MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel()
    {
        MyList = myList,
        IsPositive = IsPositive
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view you will simply check the `IsPositive` property and display the appropriate HTML:

```
@model Your.ViewModel.Namespace.MyViewModel

@if (Model.IsPositive)
{
    <h5>Please update the Positive values</h5>
}
else
{
    <h5>Please update the Negative values</h5>
}
```

Comment: Yep works perfectly thank you - I can't believe I had this brain fart. I use ViewModels in almost all of my controllers to be returned, but the combination of the way I was wiring up this particular view had my brain tangled a bit. Thanks for untangling and pointing out the obvious.